# How to change checkbox status when partial page content changes in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

Having a main page and a Partial page in main page both pages having different CheckBox controls, my requirement is when I check a checkbox in partial page the checkbox in main page should be changed. How can I achieve this in MVC view?

[image]

Attached screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By attaching jquery change event to your checkboxes as below:

```
$("#yourPartialPageCheckId").change(function() {
   $("#yourMainPageCheckId").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

And

```
$("#yourMainPageCheckId").change(function() {      
    $("#yourPartialPageCheckId").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```